# Processing a Redis queue using BLPOP causes a race condition in unit tests?

Tags: go, concurrency, redis, race-condition

I'm trying to implement a first-in, first-out task queue as described in [Chapter 6.4.1 of the Redis e-book](https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-6-application-components-in-redis/6-4-task-queues/6-4-1-first-in-first-out-queues/) in Go. For testing purposes, I'm passing in a `CommandExecutor` interface to the 'worker' function like so:

```golang
package service

import (
    "context"

    "github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

const commandsQueue = "queuedCommands:"

var pool = redis.Pool{
    MaxIdle:   50,
    MaxActive: 1000,
    Dial: func() (redis.Conn, error) {
        conn, err := redis.Dial("tcp", ":6379")
        if err != nil {
            logrus.WithError(err).Fatal("initialize Redis pool")
        }
        return conn, err
    },
}

// CommandExecutor executes a command
type CommandExecutor interface {
    Execute(string) error
}

func processQueue(ctx context.Context, done chan<- struct{}, executor CommandExecutor) error {
    rc := pool.Get()
    defer rc.Close()

    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            done <- struct{}{}
            return nil
        default:
            // If the commands queue does not exist, BLPOP blocks until another client
            // performs an LPUSH or RPUSH against it. The timeout argument of zero is
            // used to block indefinitely.
            reply, err := redis.Strings(rc.Do("BLPOP", commandsQueue, 0))
            if err != nil {
                logrus.WithError(err).Errorf("BLPOP %s %d", commandsQueue, 0)
                return errors.Wrapf(err, "BLPOP %s %d", commandsQueue, 0)
            }

            if len(reply) < 2 {
                logrus.Errorf("Expected a reply of length 2, got one of length %d", len(reply))
                return errors.Errorf("Expected a reply of length 2, got one of length %d", len(reply))
            }

            // BLPOP returns a two-element multi-bulk with the first element being the
            // name of the key where an element was popped and the second element
            // being the value of the popped element (cf. https://redis.io/commands/blpop#return-value)
            if err := executor.Execute(reply[1]); err != nil {
                return errors.Wrapf(err, "execute scheduled command: %s", reply[0])
            }
            done <- struct{}{}
        }
    }
}
```

I've made a small example repository, https://github.com/kurtpeek/process-queue, with this code as well as an attempt at unit tests. For the unit test, I have two tests which are the same (with different names):

```golang
package service

import (
    "context"
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
)

func TestProcessQueue(t *testing.T) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    executor := &CommandExecutorMock{
        ExecuteFunc: func(string) error {
            return nil
        },
    }

    done := make(chan struct{})
    go processQueue(ctx, done, executor)

    rc := pool.Get()
    defer rc.Close()

    _, err := rc.Do("RPUSH", commandsQueue, "foobar")
    require.NoError(t, err)

    <-done

    assert.Exactly(t, 1, len(executor.ExecuteCalls()))
    assert.Exactly(t, "foobar", executor.ExecuteCalls()[0].In1)
}

func TestProcessQueue2(t *testing.T) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    executor := &CommandExecutorMock{
        ExecuteFunc: func(string) error {
            return nil
        },
    }

    done := make(chan struct{})
    go processQueue(ctx, done, executor)

    rc := pool.Get()
    defer rc.Close()

    _, err := rc.Do("RPUSH", commandsQueue, "foobar")
    require.NoError(t, err)

    <-done

    assert.Exactly(t, 1, len(executor.ExecuteCalls()))
    assert.Exactly(t, "foobar", executor.ExecuteCalls()[0].In1)
}
```

where the `CommandExecutorMock` is generated using [`moq`](https://github.com/matryer/moq). If I run each test individually, they pass:

```
~/g/s/g/k/process-queue> go test ./... -v -run TestProcessQueue2
=== RUN   TestProcessQueue2
--- PASS: TestProcessQueue2 (0.00s)
PASS
ok      github.com/kurtpeek/process-queue/service   0.243s
```

However, if I run all the tests, the second one times out:

```
~/g/s/g/k/process-queue> 
go test ./... -v -timeout 10s
=== RUN   TestProcessQueue
--- PASS: TestProcessQueue (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestProcessQueue2
panic: test timed out after 10s
```

It seems that when the second test runs, the goroutine started in the first test is still running and `BLPOP`ing the command from the queue, so that the `<-done` line in the second test blocks indefinitely. This is despite calling `cancel()` on the parent context of the first test.

How can I 'isolate' these tests so that they both pass when run together? (I've tried passing the `-p 1` flag to `go test` but to no avail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is despite calling cancel() on the parent context of the first test.

There is some time between writing to `done` and calling `cancel()`, which means that the first test might (and does) enter the second `for/select` iteration instead of exiting on `<-ctx.Done()`. More specifically, the test code includes 2 assertions before the cancellation:

```
    assert.Exactly(t, 1, len(executor.ExecuteCalls()))
    assert.Exactly(t, "foobar", executor.ExecuteCalls()[0].In1)
```

Only then `defer cancel()` kicks in, which appears to be too late to cancel the context on the first go routine.

If you move `cancel()` call just before reading from `done`, the tests pass:

```golang
func TestProcessQueue(t *testing.T) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    executor := &CommandExecutorMock{
        ExecuteFunc: func(string) error {
            return nil
        },
    }

    done := make(chan struct{})
    go processQueue(ctx, done, executor)

    rc := pool.Get()
    defer rc.Close()

    _, err := rc.Do("RPUSH", commandsQueue, "foobar")
    require.NoError(t, err)

    cancel() // note this change right here
    <-done

    assert.Exactly(t, 1, len(executor.ExecuteCalls()))
    assert.Exactly(t, "foobar", executor.ExecuteCalls()[0].In1)
}
```